# Images within div no longer appearing in Chrome but appear in Safari

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I changed a div in my code to position: fixed, and it appears to make the div contents disappear.

The HTML:

```
<div id="social">
    <div id="imdb_link"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/imdb.svg"></a></div>
    <div id="insta_link"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.svg"></a></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#social{
    height: 35px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#imdb_link{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#insta_link{
    height: 20px; 
    width: 20px;
    position: relative; 
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

[The end result looks like this in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snn9W.png)

..but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be displaying in Chrome now. I should note that -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); does not appear to help.

Comment: The code you provided works fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJeBeb Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Try going to each individual file and reload it in the browser a few times. Clear the cache. This happens to me a lot when using Chrome.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm coding in Dreamweaver and the images are not appearing there either. But they appear in Safari. I don't understand that.